# Microsoft Graph API remove Check List Item

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-planner, microsoft-graph-plannertasks

I have a `plannerTask` and in its `Details` it has a `CheckList`. I use it to programatically insert `CheckListItems` in it, and it all works like a charm when inserting or retrieving the tasks.

My problem arrives when I am going to insert a new `CheckListItem` and the `CheckList` already has 20 items. It returns a `MaximumChecklistItemsOnTask` (because it is forbidden to insert more than 20 items in a check list).

Solution could be to remove the oldest item, but I am not able to do it. I have tried this:

```
var elementToRemove = oldDetails.Checklist.Where(c => c.Value.IsChecked).OrderBy(c => c.Value.LastModifiedDateTime).First();
oldDetails.Checklist = oldDetails.Checklist.Where(c => c.Value.LastModifiedDateTime <> elementToRemove.Value.LastModifiedDateTime);
```

But it throws a casting error in the second line:

> Unable to cast object of type
> 'WhereEnumerableIterator`1[System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair`2[System.String,Microsoft.Graph.PlannerChecklistItem]]'
> to type 'Microsoft.Graph.PlannerChecklistItems'.

Which is the right way to remove the oldest element from the ChecklistItem?

UPDATE:
In first place I retrieve a `plannerTask` from the server. Then I get the details from this `plannerTask`. So `oldDetails` is a `plannertaskdetails` object (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/plannertaskdetails?view=graph-rest-1.0). Inside the `plannertaskdetails` object (oldDetails), I have the `plannerchecklistitems` object (oldDetails.Checklist): https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/plannerchecklistitems?view=graph-rest-1.0.
If `plannerchecklistitems` were just a List, it would be as easy as `list.Remove(item)`, but it is not a normal list, and that is why I am not able to remove the item.

**UPDATE 2:**
I have found this way to remove the item from oldDetails:

```
oldDetails.Checklist.AdditionalData.Remove(elementToRemove.Key)
```

But, the the way I send the changes to the server is this:

```
await graphClient.Planner.Tasks(plannerTask.Id).Details.Request().Header("If-Match", oldDetails.GetEtag).UpdateAsync(newDetails)
```

As it is a PATCH request (not a PUT one), I only have in `newDetails` the records that have changed, it is, the new records. How could I specify there that a record has been deleted from the list? Sorry if my English is not good enough to express myself properly, but what I mean is that `newDetails` is not the full list, it only contains the records that must be added and I do not know how to specify in that request that one record must be deleted.

Comment: Looks like you are trying to do it server-side (i.e. transform your linq into a query)? Maybe you can just get the items first to the client and then remove like you did.

Comment: @Nikolay I was trying to do it in the client. In fact, I have in the client the plannertaskdetails (oldDetails), and the plannerChecklistItems (oldDetails.Checklist). The problem is that it has not a "removeItem" method or similar, that is why I try to "filter" in this way.